# Mapping a 2D space of 3D volumes to 1D space (a file)

Tags: math, language-agnostic, data-structures, dictionary, mapping

I have a two dimensional array of three dimensional volumes. This two dimensional array represents a top-down view of all of the three dimensional volumes.

I want to save this data to a file in such a way that I can retrieve it very quickly. My problem is that the two dimensional array may change size and shape; it's not always nice and square. This tends to leave unused sections and quite a lot of them.

My method of retrieval is currently using the volume-level 2D view to locate volumes that need to be loaded, but I am having difficulty coming up with a good data structure and storage technique. Most of the methods I have come across require the 2D view to be of the same length and width or depend on the length or the width.

It may be worthy to note that I want to avoid unused space in the file and that I also want good locality for the mapped points. When mapping points, it is pretty common to come up with a solution which works but produces odd relationships; {0, 0} must not map to anything but {0} and {1, 0} should be pretty close to {0} and not something like {34}.

How would you go about doing this in a space and time efficient manner?

Comment: But {0,1} can map to {34}, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a while back by implementing a few different space filling curves and using them to map and transform the upper dimensional data to the single dimension file. I found that a Hilbert curve worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So you are talking about just saving 2d slices of your model space right?

To be honest, I think the simplest and probably the best thing to do is just save everything.  It makes things very simple, and you can seek very easily to a specific spot in the file too.

Then, compress your file stream using zlib, or bz2, etc.  If you have a lot of zeros, it will compress very well.  When I start to do this, it sped up my HPC code quite a bit.

I can think of several more complicated things to do, but what are you really trying to achieve?  The compression will make it small, and it is nice to have a simple format.

Comment: The idea was to make search time O(1) given a specific coordinate in the 3D space and retrieve the parent element in the 2D space from the mapped 1D file. So, the file would have a layout that varies directly with the layout of the 3D space inside the 2D space. Compression would be inefficient because of the type of data we are mapping, which is generated by a PRNG and a smoothing function. The trick was only to prevent having a sparse file and facilitate fast searching, as seeking was our bottleneck in production.